# 100% height DIV inside TD

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I am trying to set the height of a DIV inside a TD to fill the height of the TD with a bit of padding for good measure.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sygad/FWw4G/) showing how it should be, (good browsers)

Strangely enough it works fine in IE7/8 but totally bombs in IE9.

Anyone have any CSS based solutions?

Comment: There is something wrong with tables in IE9.  Here is another example:  http://www.imaputz.com/cssStuff/bigFourVersion.html  This is same issue of working everywhere but IE9.

Comment: I just gave up and used divs.  I know it isn't semantically correct but it sure does look pretty :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's currently a problem with IE9. Tables are buggy at the moment. Should look fine in previous versions, Chrome, or Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

You could apply a height to the div and the table cell will adapt to it if it is taller than the cell.